# Do all Siberian Huskies have blue eyes?

Tags: dogs, pet-selection

I want to buy a Siberian Husky, and I'm interested in knowing if they all have blue eyes or if they have different eye colors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Siberian Huskies may have any of several different eye colors:

- pale blue
- dark blue
- amber
- green
- brown

In some individual dogs, one eye may be brown and the other blue (complete heterochromia), or one or both eyes may be "parti-colored," that is, half brown and half blue (partial heterochromia). All of these eye-color combinations are considered acceptable by the American Kennel Club<sup>1</sup>

<sup>1</sup> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siberian_Husky#Eyes

Answer (score 4):

The [breed standard for the Siberian Husky](https://www.akc.org/breeds/siberian_husky/breed_standard.cfm) (english spelling of Husky Siberano) from the American Kennel Club states:

> Eyes: almond shaped, moderately spaced and set a trifle obliquely.
>   Eyes may be brown or blue in color; one of each or parti-colored are
>   acceptable. Faults - Eyes set too obliquely; set too close together

So there are several eye colors allowed in this breed.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what has already been mentioned, color can change in the first few weeks of growth. So by 8 weeks old the puppy might have changed color from a blue color to something darker such as a shade of brown.

Comment: Welcome to pets.se  Can you expand on this answer a bit.  When you posted it I did a little quick research and it does that many/most are born with blue eyes that change as they get older, but neither my reference or @Zaralynda s mentions this.  A quality reference and more detail would do much to make this an even better answer.

Answer (score 0):

DNA testing of more than 6,000 dogs has revealed that a duplication on canine chromosome 18 is strongly associated with blue eyes in Siberian Huskies, according to a study published October 4, 2018, in the open-access journal PLOS Genetics by Adam Boyko and Aaron Sam’s of Embark Veterinary, Inc., and colleagues.”  As explained in the article out of the estimated 6,000 dogs they tested all of them had blue eyes. They explain if a husky doesn’t have blue eyes that could mean the genes weren’t transferred correctly and the dog is missing Chromosome 18 which could cause some minor to major problems in the dog’s eye health. Some of these problems could be blurry eyesight discoloration around the pupil and even being blind in one eye with the risk of being blind in both. The way the genes become messed up is, the male dog that holds the eye color gene can have different health problems that can cause a cell that helps assemble proteins is missing or weak. If the cell is missing, the gene that hold the eye color can’t create the needed cell that makes it blue. These health problems usually have something to do with the dog’s stomach. There aren’t any symptoms that can help the owner know if this issue is present. Scientist and doctors still aren’t sure what causes these problems within the dog’s stomach. If your huskie is female you don’t have to worry about these issues unless her eyes aren’t blue.